# Запись из одного бинарного файла в другой в СИ

Tags: c, файловый-ввод-вывод

В программе с добавлением/удалением записей в бинарный файл нужна функция для удаления записи. Каждая запись состоит из 25 char символов (имя товара) и 4 int характеристик (цена). Использовал способ "скопировать таблицу в новый файл, старый удалить, новый переименовать", но после использования этой функции запись отображается совершенно некорректно (иероглифы), за правильность функции отображения таблицы ручаюсь. Файл, откуда копируют, объявлен как глобальная переменная, как его имя и количество записей (`number_of_records`). В каком месте ошибка вывода в новый файл?

```
    void delete_record (void)
{
    FILE *output_file;
    char temp_name[] = "temp", c[25];
    unsigned int number, i, count, temp[4];
    if (!number_of_records)
    {
        printf ("No records found.\n");
        return;
    }
    printf ("Enter number: ");
    scanf ("%d", &number);
    if ((output_file = fopen (temp_name, "ab")) == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Cannot open output file.\n");
        return;
    }
    fseek (input_file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fseek (output_file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    for (i = 1; i < number; i++)
        {
            fread (&c, sizeof(char), 25, input_file);
            fread (&temp, sizeof(int), 4, input_file);
            fwrite (&c, sizeof(char), 25, output_file);
            fwrite (&temp, sizeof(int), 4, output_file);
        }
    fseek (input_file, (25*sizeof(char)+4*sizeof(int)), SEEK_CUR);
    for (i = number + 1; i <= number_of_records; i++)
        {
            fread (&c, sizeof(char), 25, input_file);
            fread (&temp, sizeof(int), 4, input_file);
            fwrite (&c, sizeof(char), 25, output_file);
            fwrite (&temp, sizeof(int), 4, output_file);
        }
    fclose (input_file); fclose (output_file);
    remove (filename); rename (temp_name, filename);
    if ((input_file = fopen (filename, "w+b")) == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Cannot open input file.\n");
        return;
    }
    number_of_records -= 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
input_file = fopen (filename, "rb")
```